# Проверка расширения файлов

Tags: jquery, javascript

Имеется такое JavaScript выражение для проверки формата файла

```
file.type.match(/image.*/)
```

Таким методом мы можем разрешить загрузку файлов имеющих MIME TYPE png,jpg,gif и т.п

Помогите составить выражение таким образом что бы можно было так же пропускать такие (mime) типы файлов как application/zip, image/vnd.adobe.photoshop

Побывал перебором match(тип один,тип второй) - не вышло, разрешает только первому типу грузиться.

Comment: `#image/.*|application/zip#`

Comment: Фигня это все, для linux и windows есть разница, где под linux можно загрузить любой файл под windows ничего вообще не грузится, перепробывал все варианты, рабочий только один, но это не то что надо.

    file.type.match(/image.*/)

Comment: программировать методом тыка очень сложно.

Comment: Было бы где доходчиво написано про эти mime типы, я бы и не задовал бы этот вопрос

Comment: Вы издеваетесь ? 
console.log(file.type);

Comment: узнать тип я и в терминале могу, а вот как написать правильно несколько типов в type.match(), вот главный вопрос

Comment: в смысле вы неспособны выучить элементарные правила regexp ? тогда сделайте по-другому `if (['image/jpeg','application/json','и так далее'].indexOf(file.type)<0) console.log('wrong type')`

Comment: Ok. Попробую !